# Do we have some kind of timeout option for docker container?

Tags: docker, containers

I have a requirement where if my containers have not been used for sometime, the containers should be stopped or killed.Timeout option will also work but I was not able to find something like this anywhere.
Is it really possible ?

Comment: There is no intrinsic timeout implemented, that does not really make sense for the concept of a container. I guess the main issue is: how is "not used for a certain time" actually defined? Not that trivial as it might appear on first sight. You could implement a simple watchdog script tracking the container's usage _if_ you can answer that question.

Comment: Custom entry point will do the job. Or some kind of a process outside the container.